# What is the enchantment for the spoon?

Tags: candy-box-2

What is the enchantment for the spoon? I think it's called the Spoon of Doom?  What does it do?

Answer (score 3):

The Enchantment for the spoon is called the Giant Spoon of Doom.

*This giant spoon is even more powerful than the regular giant spoon you could find, for example, in a teapot. It's quite slow, however.*

It makes the spoon attack very very slow, but it is very powerful now.

**Stats**
Damage: 315
Speed: Incredibly slow